# Why am I gettin a RuntimeError when running tests with nox?

Tags: python, testing, nox

I'm working on a Python module that should work for versions 3.7 to 3.11 of Python. I'm using `nox` to run the tests in multiple versions. My `noxfile.py` looks like this:

```py
import nox

@nox.session(python=["3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.11"])
def tests(session):
    session.install("pytest")
    session.run("pytest")
```

When I run the `nox` command I receive the followin error:

```bash
nox > Running session tests-3.7
nox > Creating virtual environment (virtualenv) using python3.7 in .nox/tests-3-7
nox > Command /Users/mariovagomarzal/Projects/python_project/venv/bin/python -m virtualenv /Users/mariovagomarzal/Projects/python_project/.nox/tests-3-7 -p python3.7 failed with exit code 1:
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.7'
nox > Session tests-3.7 failed.
nox > Running session tests-3.8
nox > Creating virtual environment (virtualenv) using python3.8 in .nox/tests-3-8
nox > Command /Users/mariovagomarzal/Projects/python_project/venv/bin/python -m virtualenv /Users/mariovagomarzal/Projects/python_project/.nox/tests-3-8 -p python3.8 failed with exit code 1:
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.8'
nox > Session tests-3.8 failed.
```

The other versions of Python work without problem. How can I solve this problem?